# bodegraph on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot, bodegraph

I have been trying to get the tex package bodegraph working on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine.  First off since Ubuntu ships with Texlive 2009 I had to uninstall the default version and manually install Texlive 2011.

I was then able to get `bodegraph` to output semilog grid lines, labels, and the like.  The problem is when I try to actually plot a transfer function, and `bodegraph` has to use `gnuplot`.  I get an error saying:

```
! I can't write on file `gnuplot/test/1.gnuplot'.
```

`test.tex` is the name of my input file and I am using `pdflatex`.  I have a suspicion that this has something to do with `pdflatex` not having the permissions to run `gnuplot` or to write temp files where it wants to, but I have no clue where to start digging in.

Does anyone have any experience with `bodegraph` on Ubuntu, or have seen this problem before

**EDIT** - Include MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',
    ref lines/.style={thin,blue!60},
    ref points/.style={circle, black, opacity=0.7, fill, minimum size= 3pt, inner sep=0},
    every node/.style={font=small},
    bode lines/.style={very thick, blue},
    Gclabel/.style={text=blue},
    xscale=12/3]

\begin{scope}[yscale=4/110]
\UnitedB
\semilog{-1}{2}{-50}{60}

% Breaks When The Following Line Is Added
\BodeAmp[ref lines, red!60]{-1:1.35}{POAmpAsymp{4}{2.0}+IntAmp{1}}

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. I also took the liberty to format you post a little. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help to see the available formatting

Comment: Are you running `pdflatex` using `-shell-escape`? This is required to run shell commands.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks, I tried running `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` argument and I still receive the same error.

Comment: Then I would suggest to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. This way people can compile and test it by themselves. Also, please check the directory permissions on you machine.

Comment: @MartinScharrer which directory? The directory of the `test.tex` or of the `bodegraph` package?

Comment: Well, I meant the `gnuplot/test/` directory, but see now my answer.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: you don't *have to* uninstall Ubuntu's TeXlive 2009, it's enough to make sure that your installation's executable path comes earlier in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the same error on my machine (Ubuntu 11.04, TL 2011 vanilla). The `bodegraph` package seems to be configured by default to use the output prefix `gnuplot/\jobname/` so the first plot in `test.tex` is written to `gnuplot/test/1.gnuplot`. However, you don't have neither a `gnuplot` directory nor a `test` sub-directory which aren't created for you, hence the error.

To solve this you need to change the `prefix` to e.g. `{}` (current directory):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    gnuplot def/.append style={prefix={}}, % Fixed the issue (prefix was 'gnuplot/\jobname/' before)
]
\begin{scope}
\UnitedB
\semilog{-1}{2}{-50}{60}

\BodeAmp{-1:1.35}{\POAmpAsymp{4}{2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You need to run this using `pdflatex -shell-escape` so that `gnuplot` can be executed.

Note that you forget to add the backslash before `POAmpAsymp` and `IntAmp`. I also removed all unrelated code to make a real *minimal* example.

Comment: That definitely fixed it.  They should mention that in the documentation somewhere.  It's not there (even in French).  Thanks for the _real_ MWE.  I'm still not too familiar with tikz or bodegraph, so there were only a few things I _knew_ I could take out.

Comment: @agoessling: See also [egreg's comment in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2137762#2137762). The manual seems to discuss that setting on page 5.

Comment: I'll add your note in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a gnuplot/\jobname/ directory before compiling, it's not necessary if you use windows