# No curves printed with bodegraph

Tags: texstudio, windows, bodegraph

So I just started using bodegraph but no graph at all.
Always from this pdf http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/bodegraph/bodegraph.pdf.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%   
%    \usepackage{pgf}
%    \usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph} % per i diagrammi di Bode

\begin{document}
             \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=7/4]
            \begin{scope}[yscale=3/40]
            \semilog{-2}{2}{-20}{20}
            \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples=100]{-2:2}
            {\POAmpAsymp{6}{0.3}}
            \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POAmp{6}{0.3}}
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm,yscale=3/90]
            \semilog{-2}{2}{-90}{0}
            \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples=100, const plot]{-2:2}
            {\POArgAsymp{6}{0.3}}
            \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POArg{6}{0.3}}
            \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}    
       \end{document}
```

but it only show me the empty grid.
As @Marijn suggested in a previous post, I tried only with the code for the bodegraph. Still the same...
[image]

And the result shoul look more o less like this:

[image]

Tanks in advance Fr3d

Comment: Do you have gnuplot installed?

Comment: Yes! Done yesterday already.

Comment: Well, I posted an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425211/121799). If you are aware of the twin questions, why don't you mention them in your new question? You could then simply say that the solutions there don't work for you (if that is the case).

Comment: Is this the same question or is it different: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425093/