# TikZ and Gnuplot: Put all *.gunplot and *.table in a customized folder

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

My question is an extension from the question ["bodegraph on Ubuntu 10.04"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31150/bodegraph-on-ubuntu-10-04)

Based on the answers of that question, we can either put all generated *.gnuplot in the directory `gnuplot/\jobname/`, or in the current directory with the tex file by using the accepted answer of that question.

My questions are: how to manipulate the command `gnuplot def/.append style={prefix={}}` to define a customized folder for all those generated *.gnuplot files? And a further question is: is there any tutorial talking about the configurations after `\begin{tikzpicture}`?

Take [this figure](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/bode-plot/) as an example. First of all, it would generate 16 extra files with .gnuplot or .table. I'd like to put them in a separate folder. Furthermore, for the configuration after `\begin{tikzpicture}`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',
    ref lines/.style={thin, blue!60},
    ref points/.style={circle, black, opacity=0.7, fill, minimum size= 3pt, inner sep=0},
    every node/.style={font=\small},
    bode lines/.style={very thick, blue},
    Gclabel/.style={text=blue},
    xscale=12/3]
```

I can guess their intension, but I don't know what the syntax rule is.