# Pgfplots, Gnuplot: Put all *.gnuplot and *.table in subfolder - Global setting

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfmathsetmacro\z{0.403713}
\pgfmathsetmacro\w{343.386319715305}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        gnuplot def/.append style={prefix="subdir/\jobname1-"}, % does not work
        gnuplot/.append style={prefix="subdir/\jobname2-"}, % does not work
        ]
    \begin{axis}
       \addplot[blue, samples = 100, smooth]
           gnuplot[id = exp, prefix="subdir/\jobname-", domain = 0:.05]
               {1 - exp(-\z*\w*x)/sqrt(1 - \z^2)*sin(\w*x*sqrt(1 - \z^2) + 1/cos(\z))};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}
       \addplot[blue, samples = 100, smooth]
           gnuplot[id = exp, domain = 0:.05]
               {1 - exp(-\z*\w*x)/sqrt(1 - \z^2)*sin(\w*x*sqrt(1 - \z^2) + 1/cos(\z))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `prefix` setting works when specified within the `\addplot gnuplot[prefix=]` command. However, I could not figure out to set this for all `\addplot gnuplot` commands.

Most likely following closed question asks the same:
[TikZ and Gnuplot: Put all *.gunplot and *.table in a customized folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163186/tikz-and-gnuplot-put-all-gunplot-and-table-in-a-customized-folder)

Relevant question:
[bodegraph on Ubuntu 10.04](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31150/bodegraph-on-ubuntu-10-04?lq=1)

**Note:**
Afaik, the subfolder has to be created manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that wasn't too complicated:

Putting following into the preamble does it:

`\tikzset{prefix=subdir/\jobname3-}`