# how to graph a transfer function in a bode plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bodegraph

How can be plotted a transfer function in a bodeplot. I just installed the bodegraph package, and have the ["paper"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31150/bodegraph-on-ubuntu-10-04/31155#31155) already done but I dont understand the format to input the transfer function, I dont know what is missing.

The MWE

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    gnuplot def/.append style={prefix={}}, % Fixed the issue (prefix was 'gnuplot/\jobname/' before)
]
\begin{scope}[xscale=10/3,yscale=10/110]
\UnitedB
\tikzset{
semilog lines/.style={thin, blue},
semilog lines 2/.style={semilog lines,
red!50 },
semilog half lines/.style={semilog lines 2,
dotted },
semilog label x/.style={semilog lines,
below,font=\tiny},
semilog label y/.style={semilog lines,
right,font=\tiny}
}
\semilog{0}{6}{0}{106}
\BodeGraph{0:4}{20*log10(abs(1/sqrt(1+(1*100000**t)**2)))}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**
Looking the output it says

```
Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `1.table' not found. on input line 15.
```

I don't want to edit the .sty file to update, so how can be adjusted the code?
I understand the bodeplot package uses gnuplot, so it has been checked and confirmed to be installed on the system.

**New Update**
I have reinstalled the bodegraph package, but Im still mismatching the function.The idea is to make it to look more or less to

[image]
I dont know what function is it.

Comment: The latest version of `bodegraph` is 11 years old. I do not know Bode plots, but it looks straight forward - can PGFPlots not be used?

Comment: Basically, a Bode plot is a log-log plot with dB (`10 log(y)`) verses frequency.  The tricky bit is that it takes y as as input but shows dB on the y axis, not y.

Comment: I wrote the `bodeplot` package a while ago to add features to `bodegraph`. Using that, you can plot Bode plots of transfer functions using a single `\BodeTF` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what a Bode plot is, but her is a replica of your graph in PGFPlots.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
   xmode=log, 
   xmin=1, xmax=10000000,
   ymin=0, ymax=110,
   axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,
   xlabel=$f(Hz)$,
   ylabel=$A_{ol}(dB)$,
   every axis x label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
     anchor=west},
   every axis y label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
     anchor=south,},
   tick align=outside,
   xtick={1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000},
   xticklabels={1,10,100,1k,10k,100k,1M},
   ytick={0,25,50,75,100},
   extra y ticks={106}, extra y tick labels={106},
   extra y tick style={y tick  style={draw=none}},
   axis on top=true,
   ]
  \fill[lightgray] (1,0) rectangle (10,106);
  \draw[dashed] (10,0) -- (10,106);
  \addplot[blue, thick] coordinates {(1,106) (10,106) (2000000,0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Semilog plot with single blue line and filled gray area]

Answer (score 3):

I digged out a Bode plot I used in one of my exercises. This is plotted manually, and already in dB in the y axis, with the real (red) and asymptotic (draw by hand, in this case, but there are other strategies). It has big fonts because it's normally in an inset on the page, but you can change them easily.

I hope it can help as a starting point.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(g.north),]% name and baseline are for positioning the graph
        \begin{axis}[name=g,
                height=5cm, width=0.5\linewidth,
                xmin=1, xmax=1000,xmode=log,
                ymin=0, ymax=60,
                domain=1:1000,
                xlabel = {$f$~(Hz)},
                ylabel = {$|A_v|$~(dB)},
                legend style = {nodes={right, font=\scriptsize}, at={(0.05,0.6)}, anchor=west},
                clip mode = individual,
                grid=both,
                ]
                \addplot[thick, blue, domain=1:4] {14};
                \addplot[thick, blue, domain=318:1000] {52};
                \draw [thick, blue] (4,14) node[right=8pt]{\SI{14}{dB}} -- (318,52) node[left=8pt]{\SI{52}{dB}};
                \draw [thick, blue, dashed] (318,52) -- (318,0) node[above left]{\SI{318}{Hz}};
                \draw [thick, blue, dashed] (4,14) -- (4,0) node[above left]{\SI{4}{Hz}};
                % notice that 20*log10(sqrt...) is the same as 10*log(...)
                \addplot[red] {14 % static gain
                        +10*log10(1+x*x/(4*4)) % zero
                        -10*log10(1+x*x/(318*318)) % pole
                    };
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Its a great example and not so simple, ita very valuable, and taking into account its made at hand. Thanks so much.